# Get big(250Gb) RDS PostgreSQL db dump into my local machine

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, dump, rds

My problem is to get big(250Gb) postgres dump on my local machine.

Its on AWS RDS. I tried to dump it to local machine, but it takes too long, kinda 3+ days.
Trying to find a way to dump it into S3 and download from there safely. May be you could suggest more effective way to do that. Will appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, aws does not provide a way to backup db into s3

you can take a look into this question and answers,

[Export huge database from amazon RDS to local mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291987/export-huge-database-from-amazon-rds-to-local-mysql)

here is one answer

**If the data is that big I would suggest copying the RDS snapshot on S3, as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html,).**

[Link to documentation to copy snapshot to s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html)

Comment: RDS Snapshots are only useful for restoring back to RDS.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered in this StackOverflow thread [Exporting a AWS Postgres RDS Table to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899210/exporting-a-aws-postgres-rds-table-to-aws-s3)

Another solution would be to spin up an EC2 instance and dump the database to a local EBS volume that is large enough for the following steps. Then chose one of the following:

1. Compress the DB dump into multiple files and copy to S3 for download. I would use a smart S3 download manager given the size of the database dump.
2. Export the S3 data using Snowball [Export S3 Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/create-export-job-steps.html). If your Internet connection is not fast enough / reliable enough then Snowball will get you the data.